# rails 4: creating custom search form with custom routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I think this should be an easy problem, but I just can't figure it out right now. Been coding all day, need another set of eyes.

Current URL is being displayed:

```
http://localhost:3000/q?utf8=✓&query%5Bquery%5D=testing
```

as opposed to

```
http://localhost:3000/q?query=testing
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :biz do
    member do
      get 'photo'
    end
  end
  get '/q' => 'search#index', as: :search


  root 'welcome#index'

end
```

**welcome/index.haml**

```
= simple_form_for :query, url: search_path, method: "get" do |q|
  = q.input :query
```

I have a **search_controller.rb**

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if params.has_key?(:query)
      @query = Model.q(params[:query])
    else
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
end
```

What should I need to fix or add?

**Form from inspector**

```
<form novalidate="novalidate" class="simple_form /q" action="/q" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get">
  <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">        
  <div class="form-group string required query_query">
    <label class="string required control-label" for="query_query">
      <abbr title="required"></abbr> Query
    </label>
  <input class="string required form-control" type="text" name="query[query]" id="query_query">      
  </div>           
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove the /:query as your sending it as a query param not a path param.
make it `/q`

Also form might have to be

`= simple_form_for :search, url: search_path do |q|`

The form will submit http://example.com/q?query=this not http://example.com/q/this/

URL issue,

The problem is the simple form is wrapping it in a model. So your params would be `params[:query][:query]` for the input. You can just you `text_field_tag 'query'` instead of `q.input :query`

Comment: still getting a no route match. I removed the /:query. This error: `No route matches [POST] "/"`

Comment: `simple_form_for search_path, method: "get" do |q|` The form is a post by default and your route is a get.

Comment: I'm getting closer! no error, but it doesn't go to the search page, it stays on the welcome page (where the input field is), and nothing happens except for the url, it changes to this: `http://localhost:3000/?utf8=✓&%2Fb%5Bquery%5D=testing` When I type testing. it doesn't go to `http://localhost:3000/q?query=testing` like you mentioned

Comment: can you paste your full routes definition now? Can't see what you have in front of you. and inspect the form on the page and tell us what the <form> tag shows.

Comment: have updated my answer with a revision, maybe you didn't do /q

Comment: updated my question up there. i added the `/` but still didn't work

Comment: `"name="/q[query]"` is invalid. Please update all with the error, not "still didn't work"

Comment: I don't get an error, the page just doesn't go anywhere, it just changes the URL with the string without redirecting to the search page.

Comment: First off, thanks for helping me! Really appreciate it. So I'm getting close to where its supposed to be, its going to the page, but the URL isn't coming out how its supposed to be like you suggested `q?query=this`. Instead, its shooting out the ugly url: `http://localhost:3000/q?utf8=✓&query%5Bquery%5D=this`

Comment: The url is wrong because of `name="/q[query]"` you really need to update the post so we can establish what you have.

Comment: i just updated the post to show what i currently have

Comment: changing it to `= text_field_tag 'query'` did the trick. Thank you!